# How To highlight imageview using button click event in android

Tags: android-layout

I m new to android Development

i have to place 3 button on screen and below that 3 image will be place below that..when i click on any button ,particular image should be highlight.
can anyone tell me how to start..i only want suggestion from where to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the image with a highlighted variation in the on click event.